# iTextsharp - c# - PDF not readable

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

When i am using iTextSharp for read and edit my pdf file i don't find any 'acroform', so i cannot edit it.
The PDf is create by Excel (office 365).
Link to my pdf : [here the file](https://www.cjoint.com/c/ICqox6suEuw)

My code :

```
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(existingFileStream);
            PdfDictionary root = reader.Catalog;
            PdfDictionary form = root.GetAsDict(PdfName.ACROFORM);
            PdfArray fields = form.GetAsArray(PdfName.FIELDS);
```

My objective is to edit the file and place data to it at specifics locations.
I hope its clear for you, 
Thanks.

Comment: *"i don't find any 'acroform'"* - indeed, there is no **AcroForm** form definition in the PDF, it is merely all text, dots, and a box symbol, no form.   *"My objective is to edit the file and place data to it at specifics locations."* - In that case you should create a PDF with an **AcroForm** form definition. I don't know whether Excel can be used for that.

Comment: Ok,  so i am not using the right method. Thanks you.